# Is it possible to prevent an Intent from proceeding ("eat" the Intent)?

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to watch for a particular SMS, and handle it in a Receiver when it arrives. I then want to "eat it" so that it doesn't bubble upwards and display to the user (it should be handled "silently"). Is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: **You should learn the android lingo so we can better/more easily understand your question.** 

If I understand right, you mean silently by "catching" that sms message when it arrives and **REMOVE** it from the database, so that it does not show up as a Notification.? Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, I don't want the user to see the message if it matches the criteria I'm looking for (that is, it belongs to my app); of course, if it's not to be intercepted by my app, then I want to "pass it on up the line."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this possible? If so, how?

Since the SMS broadcast happens to be an ordered broadcast, your `BroadcastReceiver` can call `abortBroadcast()` to stop it from being handled by lower-priority receivers.

[Here is a blog post](http://commonsware.com/blog/2010/08/11/activity-notification-ordered-broadcast.html) from a while back discussing ordered broadcasts. [Here is a sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Broadcast/Ordered) based upon that blog post. [Here is a sample SMS `BroadcastReceiver`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/SMS/Monitor) that conditionally executes `abortBroadcast()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
I then want to "eat it" so that it doesn't bubble upwards and display to the user (it should be handled "silently")
```

Huh? Intents that you register to receive **are** handled silently **unless** you choose to handle it "loudly".

**EDIT**

Also, there is no way to prevent other apps from responding to SMS messages. Think about the security implications of allowing one app to control whether other apps can listen for system events...

Comment: OK, but an SMS would normally still get seen by the user, even though I "peeked" at it first, if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the Service construct in Android.  It is designed to run something, without requiring a UI (like an Activity).

BroadcastReceiver is additional functionality you should research to catch the SMS event.

Comment: I considered using a Service, but the BroadcastReceiver IS what I'm using, and should work just dandy.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can be aborted by abortBroadcast() method and if you set priority of IntentFilter to 1000(highest priority) then this receiver will receive broadcast before the system.